# Where can I download FluxJpeg from?

Tags: silverlight, image, jpeg, codec, fjcore

What happened to the home page of FluxJpeg (or FJCore)? Many pages point to
http://code.google.com/p/fjcore/
but that page has no downloads available as of today (June 28, 2011).

Q1) Where can I download it from?

Q2) Is there anything better? I need an open-source class that I can use from Silverlight 4 to decode a JPEG, reduce its size (preferably using some interpolation algorithm) and encode it back to JPEG, to upload the file to a server.

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're supposed to use Subversion to check out the source, and then build it yourself: http://code.google.com/p/fjcore/source/checkout.

Alternatively, you can use LibJpeg.NET: http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg/. It's a straightforward port of the unofficially canonical libjpeg. Only downside is that it's more complex and a bit harder to hack on.

Comment: Ken, thanks. I've never used Subversion, but I'll try it. And LibJpeg.NET is one of two that I'm considering. It seems very well documented. Lovely .chm file.

Answer (score 0):

**Q2.**

Have a look at [imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php) Very stable, tons of functionality and the likelihood that it'll disappear is close to 0

Comment: I had seen imagemagick before making my question, but it didn't convince me 100%. Can it be called from managed code (SL4)? Will I need to deploy a huge .dll inside my .xap file, or I will be able to choose only JPEG codec, for instance? Thanks.

Comment: A solution could be to use A + B:

A) JPEG codec : http://bitmiracle.com/libjpeg/

B) Resize library with bilinear interpolation : http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/

I'm studying them.

Comment: In brief, no, you can't use imagemagick in browser-based Silverlight. It's native code, not managed. You could hack together a solution using it if you were using OOB Silverlight, but I can't imagine why you'd want to go through the hassle.

Comment: In the end, I have not needed a resize library. Just the bitmiracle LipJpeg has been enough, because the decompression process gives me the option to produce an output image (bitmap) that is 1/1, 1/2, 1/4 or 1/8 the size of the original size. Those ratios are enough for me, since I just want to reduce size of pictures before uploading them to a server. With a quality setting of 85 (out of 100) the result is great. I'm very happy with the BitMiracle LibJpeg library. Very easy to use, if you read the .chm file. Thanks!